# Set gtk property using vala

Tags: gtk, vala

I am trying to make my first app in vala. I made a ui in glade with a headerbar, now I want the headerbar to show the window controls. I searched how to set a gtk property with vala but couldn't really find an answer. I could find the property which I needed to set but not how to set it in vala. The current code of my main application in vala now is this:

```
using Gtk;

public static int main(string[] args){
    Gtk.init (ref args);
    try{
        var builder = new Builder();
        builder.add_from_file ("Headerbar.ui");
        builder.connect_signals (null);
        var window = builder.get_object ("main_window") as Window;
        var headerbar = builder.get_object ("headerbar") as Gtk.HeaderBar;
        headerbar.set_show_close_button(true);
        window.show_all ();
        Gtk.main ();
    } catch (Error e){
        stderr.printf ("Kon ui niet laden: %s\n", e.message);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code of my ui file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="main_window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkLabel" id="label">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child type="titlebar">
          <object class="GtkHeaderBar">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="sayhello">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Say hello!    </property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
</child>
```

When i compile the code it does not give any errors. But when i run the application, the window controls aren't showed in the header bar and i get the following error in the terminal: 
(main:15420): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_header_bar_set_show_close_button: assertion 'GTK_IS_HEADER_BAR (bar)' failed.
How can i properly set the property so that the headerbar shows the window controls.

Comment: Your xml does not contain the id "headerbar" that you use in the code

Comment: @jku thank your very much, I thought I specified the id in glade but apparently I didn't, thank you and have a nice day.